# Best way to query without a join table ActiveRecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, activerecord

So I have a table `trips` and a table `conditions`. `Trips` has a `start_date` and `end_date`, and neither last more than a few hours on the same day. Conditions has a `date` column. I am trying to compare them to find the `trip.id` of a `date` in order to seed with a `:trip_id` foreign key located in the `conditions` table with a very large csv. I understand that it is a many_to_many relationship, but I am wondering how to convert what I wrote in Ruby (transitioning to rails currently) to the "ActiveRecord" way without hitting the database so many times.

Here is my code:

**Helper method**

```
def self.id_by_date(date)
  find_by(date: date).id
end
```

**Main method**

```
def self.sort_temp(range)
    array = where(max_temperature: range).all.map {|condition| condition.date}
    trip_nums = array.map do |date|
      Trip.where(start_date: date.beginning_of_day...date.end_of_day).count
    end
    output = {}
    output[:max] = trip_nums.sort.last
    output[:min] = trip_nums.sort.reverse.last
    output[:avg] = trip_nums.inject(:+) / trip_nums.length unless trip_nums.length == 0
    output
end
```

EDIT: To be clear, I am trying to find all conditions associated with a day

Comment: What do your models look like? It looks like you're not letting Rails and SQL do the work for you. Also, you're sorting your `trip_nums` twice. You have `trip_nums.sort.last` and `trip_nums.sort.reverse.last`. Ruby has methods for Array class for that. `output[:max] = trip_nums.max` and `output[:min] = trip_nums.min`.

Comment: @lurker Trips has many conditions and Conditions belong to Trip